# How to run executable after bootup automatically in linux

Tags: linux, yocto

I am using poky build toolchain for I.MX6 board. Using kernel version 3.14.38 and poky version 1.8. I am able to run the application manually after bootup with command ./Executable. But the application needs to be ran after bootup automatically. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: [This](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Cookbook:Appliance:Startup_Scripts) cookbook item explains how to add startup scripts to a Yocto image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Frank stated, you can provide an initscript to start your program. Like I did in this [recipe](https://github.com/graugans/meta-udoo/blob/krogoth/recipes-support/udoofota/udoofota_1.0.bb)

You'll find more details about [INITSCRIPT_NAME](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8.2/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-INITSCRIPT_NAME) in the [Yocto Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8.2/ref-manual/ref-manual.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the init system for that.
See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init. Depending on your system setup you will have a busybox-init, sysv-init or a systemd. Find out what you have and use it to start your program automatically.